# 'sqlConnection.InnerConnection.ServerVersionNormalized' Threw an Exception (Connection open, sqldatareader not working)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

This seems to be a problem either with my computer or the azure sql servers. The problem I have was not a problem before but the code all of a sudden acting strange. Here is my code that is used to work. Connection opens successfully, my executenonquery works fine but reader acts strange.

```
public static List<ClientDto> GetClientInformation()
        {
            List<ClientDto> results = new List<ClientDto>();
            try
            {
                using (var sqlConnection =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientData"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(null, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        //running the GetClientInformation stored procedure in DB
                        command.CommandText = Constants.GetClientInformation;

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            results.Add(new ClientDto()
                            {
                                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"].ToString()),
                                DealerName = reader["DealerName"].ToString(),
                                GroupID = reader["GroupID"].ToString(),
                                DealerId = reader["DealerId"].ToString(),
                                DealerFolderName = reader["DealerFolder"].ToString(),
                                DMSType = reader["DMSType"].ToString(),
                                MAIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["MAIsActive"])),
                                SalesIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["SalesIsActive"])),
                                SalesSource = reader["SalesSource"].ToString(),
                                InventoryIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["InventoryIsActive"])),
                                InventorySource = reader["InventorySource"].ToString(),
                                AppointmentsIsActive =
                                    Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["AppointmentsIsActive"])),
                                AppointmentsSource = reader["AppointmentsSource"].ToString(),
                                LeadsIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["LeadsIsActive"])),
                                LeadsSource = reader["LeadsSource"].ToString(),
                                ServiceIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["ServiceIsActive"])),
                                ServiceSource = reader["ServiceSource"].ToString(),
                                SalesIsDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["SalesIsDelete"])),
                                SalesDeleteRange = reader["SalesDeleteRange"].ToString(),
                                InventoryIsDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["InventoryIsDelete"])),
                                InventoryDeleteRange = reader["InventoryDeleteRange"].ToString(),
                                AppointmentsIsDelete =
                                    Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["AppointmentsIsDelete"])),
                                AppointmentsDeleteRange = reader["AppointmentsDeleteRange"].ToString(),
                                LeadsIsDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["LeadsIsDelete"])),
                                LeadsDeleteRange = reader["LeadsDeleteRange"].ToString(),
                                ServiceIsDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["ServiceIsDelete"])),
                                ServiceDeleteRange = reader["ServiceDeleteRange"].ToString(),
                                IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsActive"])),
                                UserDefinedName = reader["UserDefinedName"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //If an exception happens it will insert the error to errorlog table and to the log file
                Logger.WriteError(new ErrorDto()
                {
                    Source = "GetClientInformation",
                    Message = ex.Message,
                    StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
                });
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error - {0} - {1} ", "GetClientInformation", ex.Message));

                return results;
            }
            }
```

There is data in the sql, the executable of my application works fine on our virtual machine (Windows Server). 
Only strange thing I see in the code is that SQLConnection have this innerexception (it is not stopping the code to run though) 
ServerVersionNormalized = 'sqlConnection.InnerConnection.ServerVersionNormalized' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' 
I am not sure if this was an issue before or not.

[This picture shows that Enamration yielded no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIy6L.png)

[This picture shows that reader has rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbHFU.png)

I am reinstalling my visual studio now to see if it will fix the issue. 
This issue is happening in both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 for me.

This is my connection string format:
Server=.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;             User ID=;Password=;Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True;

Comment: check your sql server version. Not VS.

Comment: Nothing have changed in the sql server as far as I am aware, it is an azure server and it was 2012 when it was working and it is 2012 now too, unless there are changes in Azure that I am not aware of.

Comment: is it sql server or azure db?

Comment: It is an Azure DB created on an Azure SQL Server

Comment: then read up the document and see if that is supported. im suspecting its your stored procedure call that's causing the trouble

Comment: The problem is that this was working a week ago completely fine and it is still working fine when it is being ran on VM using the executable. It is on my computer using visual studio to run the application that seems to be having problem and that is why I thought the problem most likely is with my computer

Comment: if you are running an Azure VM that's located inside the same account as your db then it might has to do with security settings. just a wild guess

Comment: No the VM is separated from the db and I can connect to the DB on my application fine, I can even write data to table, reading is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is working fine now. To me it sounds like since I had breakpoint in the code, it might have caused the issue because of the longer time between connecting and running the query.